# Using "extends" in RABL when the required node is not attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

When a required node is an attribute or method, it is easy to call extends.

But when it is not an attribute? It could be an instance variable or an attr accessor.

Example below:

---

```
// dispatches is an attribute of the class
child :dispatches => :dispatches do
  extends "/dispatches/_base"
end

# completed post is not an attribute of the class
if @completed_post
  node(:post) do |post|
    {
      id: @completed_post.id.to_s,
      _id: @completed_post.id.to_s,
      display_text: @completed_post.display_text,
      # and many others
    }
end
```

This required additional node could either be an @instance or @object[:some_attribute]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help you but you can pass "locals" to extended template like so:

```
extends('posts/show', :locals => { :hide_comments => true })
```

Then in your `posts/show` template:

```
# app/views/posts/show.json.rabl
object @post

node(:comments) { |post| post.comments } unless locals[:hide_comments]
```